# Line length counting bash

Tags: bash, awk, uniq

If I have an example file that contains

```
11
11
0
11
11
11
11
0
```

and ran the uniq -c command why does it give me as output

```
2 11
1 0
4 11
1 0
```

Instead of

```
6 11
2 0
```

How can I make my output as above rather than it splitting it into strange groups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is answered from the manual.  The input needs to be sorted.

```
The uniq utility reads the standard input comparing adjacent lines, and
writes a copy of each unique input line to the standard output.  The sec-
ond and succeeding copies of identical adjacent input lines are not writ-
ten.  Repeated lines in the input will not be detected if they are not
adjacent, so it may be necessary to sort the files first.
```

Say:

```
sort inputfile | uniq -c
```

Comment: much appreciated, a simple mistake on my part (I actually just had uniq and sort on the wrong side of eachother and was too frustrated to notice) once again thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` for this:

```
awk '{a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) print a[i],i}' file
6 11
2 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sort the file first. So the following command would help:

> sort test.txt | uniq -c

This would give you the following output:

> 2 0
>
> 6 11

You might also need to use different sorting options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just one command

> sort -u filetosort.txt